# Templated assignment operator failed template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to build a templated base class that allows for assignment to any of its template types, like so:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename T1, typename... Types>
class Base
{
    public:
    //assignment to base or derived class
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base<T1, Types...>, T>::value>::type = 0>
    Base& operator=(T&& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
            a = other.a;
        return *this;
    }

    //assignment to other type contained in <T1, Types...>
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Base<T1, Types...>, T>::value>::type = 0>
    Base& operator=(T&& other)
    {
        // do some stuff
        return *this;
    }


    private:
    int a;
};
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use `std::enable_if` to differentiate assignment to a `Base` (move or copy) and assignment to a type by wrapping `std::is_base_of`. I'm under the impression that `T&&` should bind to `const Base&`, `Base&&`, `Base&`, as well as `const T&` `T&&`, etc.

The problem happens when I try to create a derived class that supports the assignment by simply forwarding the arguments to the base:

```
class Derived : public Base<int, double>
{
    public:
    // similar pattern here, but call base class' operators
    // for both copy/move assignment
    // as well as assignment to int or double
    template<typename T>
    Derived& operator=(T&& other)
    {
        Base<int, double>::operator=(std::forward<T>(other));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

As soon as I try to do what I think should be a valid assignment, the compiler tells me that it failed to perform template deduction/substitution.

```
int main() {
    Derived foo;
    int a = 4;
    foo = a;
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please go easy on me.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/turf2w)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

1. For lvalues the *forwarding-reference* (as well as the template type parameter `T` itself) becomes an *lvalue reference*. You should *decay* type `T` prior to checking if it's a subclass of other type.
2. You are using `std::enable_if` in a wrong way; if you want to utilize `::type = 0` syntax then it needs some other type than the default `void` one.

Having that said, your `std::enable_if` syntax should look as follows:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base<T1, Types...>
                                       , typename std::decay<T>::type // decay of T
                                       >::value
                      , int>::type = 0 // int as a second template argument
```

Complete example:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base<T1, Types...>, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value, int>::type = 0>
Base& operator=(T&& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
        a = other.a;
    return *this;
}

//assignment to other type contained in <T1, Types...>
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Base<T1, Types...>, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value, int>::type = 0>
Base& operator=(T&& other)
{
    // do some stuff
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: All the examples I see of `enable_if` use a `= 0` or `= nullptr` idiom (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), and admittedly I'm just trying to copy that. Can you explain a little more about that?

Comment: @AndyG yes they do, but they put asterisk `*` after `::type`, so it becomes `::type* = 0` and when successfully instantiated: `void* = 0` (or `int* = 0`, or `int* = nullptr`). Without asterisk, you end up with `void = 0` which is not valid

Comment: Ah, I see. Dropping the `int` and using `::type* = nullptr` worked for me. Thank you so much, this issue has been bothering me ceaselessly!

Comment: Note that `void *` is technically not a legal type for a template non-type parameter, though most compilers support it anyway.